# String formulation in Java

Tags: java, string, http, url

I need to compose an URL string in javaME (which doesn't allow me to work with many libraries which would do this in a no time) like this

```
     url = "http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":"+wordX+",\"RS\":20/04/13-2008:31:44,\"SER\":"+net2+"}";
```

This is producion a string like this:

```
http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={"Word":358741051173885,"RS":20/04/13-2008:31:44,"SER":53543d303b44523d4e616fd}
```

The thing is I need the values to also be inside commas. I have tried everything but I'm not being able to understand how to do it.
Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: "_I need the values to also be inside commas_". Please elaborate with examples.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many json libraries? for example jackson?

Comment: Do you mean that values should also be quoted ? `http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={"Word":"358741051173885","RS":"20/04/13-2008:31:44","SER":"53543d303b44523d4e616fd"}`

Comment: I hope this is what you are expecting..
String str = "http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\"358741051173885\",\"RS\":\"20/04/13-2008:31:44\",\"SER\":\"53543d303b44523d4e616fd\"}";

Comment: That's exactly what I want but declarationg the variable names WordX and Net2 instead of passing the values!

Comment: @kohhworlwide just add quotes, no?! `\""+wordX+"\"` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `MessageFormat`:

```
final MessageFormat urlFormat = new MessageFormat("http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\"{0}\",\"RS\":20/04/13-2008:31:44,\"SER\":\"{1}\"}");
```

Then simply apply your values to the format:

```
final String url = urlFormat.format(new Object[]{wordX, net2});
```

Or, create a format `String`:

```
final String urlFormat = "http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\"%s\",\"RS\":20/04/13-2008:31:44,\"SER\":\"%s\"}";
```

And use `String.format`:

```
final String url = String.format(urlFormat, wordX, net2);
```

Or, just change you `String` to:

```
url = "http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\""+wordX+"\",\"RS\":20/04/13-2008:31:44,\"SER\":\""+net2+"\"}";
```

Comment: I can't do it because this is for a javaME project, which implies not using anything above 1.3 jre. 

I forgot to mention it in the question.
My bad!

Comment: @kohhworlwide a slightly major omission don't you think?!

Comment: Indeed it was! haha

Comment: @kohhworlwide I've added a final option, which should for work you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Boris! Happy Halloween haha.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
String url = String.format("http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\"%s\",\"RS\":20/04/13-2008:31:44,\"SER\":\"%s\"}", wordX, net2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String val1 = "";
    String val2 = "";

    String str =    "http://helloworld.com/index.php?data={\"Word\":\""+val1+"\",\"RS\":\"20/04/13-2008:31:44\",\"SER\":\""+val2+"\"}";
```